# Typescript accepts ENUM as a interface value but returns error when receive the props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums, next.js

I created a UI library, to standardize things like sizes and colors, I created an ENUM to specify each value.

```
export enum sizes {
   small = 'small',
   medium = 'medium',
   large = 'large',
}

export enum colors {
   orange = 'orange',
   purple = 'purple',
   transparent = 'transparent',
}
```

And I passed this ENUM as a value in the props interface

```
export interface ButtonProps {
    children: React.ReactNode,
    text?: string,
    colors: colors,
    disabled?: boolean,
    size?: sizes,
    onClick?: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>
}
```

So far everything working perfectly, in the storybook the values are perfectly set, and the library builds without problems.

[image]

But for some reason, when using the component as an installable dependency in the main application, when I set these values, an error appears in vscode.

[image]
[image]

But even with this error in the middle of the screen, when I go to localhost:3000, the components are there perfectly, receiving the correct values and working normally

[image]

It's my first time using ENUM, does anyone know where I made the mistake and how can I fix it?
Sorry for the amount of images, it was the best way to illustrate the error.

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting your `enum` as `const`:

```
export const enum sizes {
 small = "small",
 medium = "medium",
 large = "large"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using TypeScript your VSCode tries to warn you that you are not using an enum for that attribute, you are using a string for that attribute.

You can avoid those warnings (and I recommend doing this for code maintainability) by doing this:

```
<Button color={colors.purple} size={sizes.small}>
    Test
</Button>
```

Also don't forget to import `colors` and `sizes` into your component.
If in the future you change the properties on your enum, VSCode will warn you that the property has changed and is no longer supported.

Another thing, enums should be written in Pascal Case (similar to JAVA) to make them more easy to understand when reading code.

```
export enum Sizes {
 Small = "small",
 Medium = "medium",
 Large = "large"
}
```

Comment: Hey, but this enums are in the UI-lib repo, and the error is in another repo, so i cant access this.

Comment: Then you should export those enums to make them available outside your library